# setInterval not updating DOM every second

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a countdown timer for a prize competitions website but the time seems to only show 1 output and does not decrement by a second like it should. The console.log is also only showing one output.

Here are my methods:

```
getClosingCompetitions() {
    this.$axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://rafflear.test/api/get-closing-competitions',
        config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }}
    })
    .then(response => {
        this.closingComps = response.data;
        setInterval(this.countdown(), 1000);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
    })
},
countdown() {
    this.closingComps.map((e, index) => {
        let now = moment();
        let expiration = moment(e.end_date);
        let diff = expiration.diff(now);
        let diffDuration = moment.duration(diff);
        this.timer[index] = diffDuration.days() + " days " + diffDuration.hours() + " hours " + diffDuration.minutes() + " mins " + diffDuration.seconds() + " secs";
    });
}
```

And here is the DOM:

```
v-row>
    <v-col v-for="(item, index) in closingComps" :key="item.id" md="3">
        <v-card class="pa-2 latest-competitions">
            <span class="text-caption">
                {{ timer[index] }}
            </span>
        </v-card>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Comment: `setInterval(this.countdown(), 1000);` <= this is a well known improper usage of a setInterval.  The first argument is expected to be a callback, not an invocation.  Ex. `() => this.countdown()`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying there @Sphinx

Comment: Ok, so changing it to: window.setInterval(() => this.countdown()); is giving me correct console,log output but still not showing up on the DOM.

Comment: check the data properties in Vue DevTools, if all data properties are correct but the DOM is not updated, that means the reactivity was triggerred

Answer (score 2):

You are currently assigning the return value of `countdown` to [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead of the function itself to be used as a callback. To keep the `this` reference, you can either use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or [`Function#bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

```
setInterval(()=>this.countdown(), 1000);
//or
setInterval(this.countdown.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: Still not showing on the DOM but console.log shows the correct output and updates every second.

Comment: try this: change `this.timer[index] = diffDuration.days()..` to `this.$set(this.timer, index, diffDuration.days()...`; Refer to [Vue Guide: Reactivity in Depth](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#ad)

Comment: That worked @Sphinx but why is the normal/more traditional method not working?

Comment: Read this guide: [Vue Guide: Reactivity in Depth](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#ad)